# No handler registered for channel - Electron IPC handle/invoke

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, ipc

In my electron app, I am receiving an error "No handler registered for 'channel-name' at EventEmitter../lib/renderer/api/ipc-renderer.ts.ipcRenderer.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:1163:19)". IPC handle is not registered and the communication between renderer and main process is not working as expected in Windows.

When I open the app from windows installer, I see this issue and it's intermittent when open the app from the applications on windows.

Here is the code snippet of how I used ipc handle/invoke.

In Main.ts file

```
import {ipcMain} from 'electron';
private registerIpcChannels(ipcChannels: IpcChannelInterface[]) {
        try {
            for(const channel of ipcChannels) {
                ipcMain.handle(channel.getName(), async (event, request) => await channel.handleInvoke(event, request))
            }
        } catch (err) {
            log.error(`Unable to register IPC channels: ${err.message}`, err);
        }
    }
```

In Renderer.js file:

```
import electron from 'electron';
sendMessage(msg) {
        let ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;
        ipc.invoke(channelName, msg);
}
```

I don't understand that why it is working completely fine in MacOS but not on windows. I followed the documentation to implement handle/invoke in electron app.
Environment info:
Electron - v8.5.2
Nodejs - v12.16.1
OS - Windows 10

**Note: This is happening only at the time of first-time launch. After refresh or quit and reopen the app, it works fine**

Can anyone help to figure out why this issue is occurring?

Comment: we don't really have enough information to go off of. For starters, we'd need to know what `channelName` is set to in the renderer and we'd need to know when `sendMessage` is triggered. Could there be a race condition where that code runs before the main process has registered the listeners? And when is `registerIpcChannels` called, and what channels are passed into it.

Comment: @pushkin registerIpcChannels function is called in the constructor of Main.ts file (mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270268/electron-race-condition-between-main-and-renderer-process) and sendMessage is triggered by a class which gets called when the MainWindow is being created. The main window is being created at the time when app.on('ready') event fired.

Comment: step through your code and see what channels are getting added in the main process and what channels are being used in the rendererr

Comment: Anyone coming here for getting this error on every run, check to make sure you're registering the handler with the appropriate `ipcMain.on()` or `ipcMain.handle()` call. Their channels are in different namespaces.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue. My problem was that I was instructing electron to navigate to my app *before* my IPC handlers were being registered. The reason it was only happening on the first load and not subsequent loads/reloads (and hot-reloads) was because the BrowserWindow was getting recreated and my IPC handlers were already registered (and getting re-registered in my code).

So be absolutely sure that your handlers are being registered before the BrowserWindow loads the renderer code that calls the IPC channels.

Comment: This is definitely the issue OP is facing.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: This is happening only at the time of first-time launch. After refresh or quit and reopen the app, it works fine

That is so because once you launch electron it uses the saved settings and codes in the main process. **If you change a code in the main process then you must quit the app and relaunch to effect the changes made in main process code**

I hope the information above saves someones time!

Answer (score 0):

handle should be placed before main window created;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).